# Remove builds from conda custom channel with same version

Tags: conda, conda-build

In a custom conda channel for a DEV environment, we may and up with several builds having the same version number. This can just be caused by several merges into the develop branch and triggering your CID process.

Is there an accurate way to ensure that any consumer, of this package, would only use the very latest? Maybe by removing any previous build with the == version?

I'm utilising the `build_number`, which unique for every build.

Answer (score 0):

Conda will favor latest build, all else being equal, so there should be no reason to remove builds as long as the build numbers are incrementing.